# ubuntu dereference links when copying in nautilus

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, nautilus

I recently collected a bunch of files I wished to share as a folder of links, and then dropped that in my Dropbox, these then appeared as symlinks to the other people using the folder and were quite useless. Is there any way to automatically dereference these links when copying from the file browser?

I know I can `cp -L`, but if there's any way to do this without the terminal that would be great.

Comment: My google-fu may be failing me, but it looks like there's currently no way to do this. ):

Comment: I just assumed mine failed me as well, hence checking in here. Wow, that's really frustrating. Sounds like time to hack a "Copy + Paste with dereference" into Nautilus.

Comment: I could probably write it in Vala in a while